Add ignore_changes for read,write capactiy in dynamic GSI block
I am trying to add ignore_changes for GSI read and write capacity in the code block below. I have tried several methods to make it work, but with no luck.
main.tf :
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default" {
  count            = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  name             = var.name
  billing_mode     = var.billing_mode
  read_capacity    = var.dynamodb_read_capacity
  write_capacity   = var.dynamodb_write_capacity
  hash_key         = var.hash_key
  range_key        = var.range_key
  stream_enabled   = var.enable_streams
  stream_view_type = var.enable_streams ? var.stream_view_type : ""

  server_side_encryption {
    enabled = var.enable_encryption
    kms_key_arn = var.kms_key_arn
  }

  point_in_time_recovery {
    enabled = var.enable_point_in_time_recovery
  }

  dynamic "attribute" {
    for_each = local.attributes_final
    content {
      name = attribute.value.name
      type = attribute.value.type
    }
  }

  dynamic "global_secondary_index" {
    for_each = var.global_secondary_index_map
    content {
      hash_key           = global_secondary_index.value.hash_key
      name               = global_secondary_index.value.name
      non_key_attributes = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "non_key_attributes", null)
      projection_type    = global_secondary_index.value.projection_type
      range_key          = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "range_key", null)
      read_capacity      = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "read_capacity", null)
      write_capacity     = lookup(global_secondary_index.value, "write_capacity", null)
    }
  }

  ttl {
    attribute_name = var.ttl_attribute
    enabled        = var.ttl_attribute != "" && var.ttl_attribute != null ?  true : false
  }

  tags = var.tags

  lifecycle {
//    ignore_changes = [
//      read_capacity,
//      write_capacity,
//      global_secondary_index[*].read_capacity,
//      global_secondary_index[*].write_capacity
//    ]
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

module:
module "test" {
  source                        = "../tf-module/dynamodb"
  enabled                       = local.env == "uat" ? false : local.env == "lt" ? false : local.env == "prod" ? true : false
  name                          = "${local.env}-test"
  hash_key                      = "testhashkey"
  dynamodb_read_capacity        = local.test-read
  dynamodb_write_capacity       = local.test-write
  read_target_value             = local.test-read-target-value
  write_target_value            = local.test-write-target-value
  enable_point_in_time_recovery = local.env == "prod" ? true : false
  tags                          = merge(tomap({ "Name" = join("-", [local.env, local.project, "test"]) }), tomap({ "ResourceType" = "dynamodb" }), local.common_tags)
}

Could anyone kindly provide a solution on how to set ignore_changes for the read and write capacity of a dynamic GSI block?
I am getting below error:
│ Error: Invalid expression
│
│   on ../tf-module/dynamodb/main.tf line 108, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default":
│  108:       global_secondary_index[*].write_capacity
│
│ A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template expressions, etc are allowed here.

I have tried with global_secondary_index.read_capacity and global_secondary_index.write_capacity instead, and got a different error:
│   on ../tf-module/dynamodb/main.tf line 107, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default":
│  107:       global_secondary_index.read_capacity
│
│ Block type "global_secondary_index" is represented by a set of objects, and set elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific criteria, use a "for" expression with an "if" clause.


What is the issue you have with the current code?

Hi @MarkoE , I am getting below error : │ Error: Invalid expression │ │   on ../tf-module/dynamodb/main.tf line 108, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default": │  108:       global_secondary_index[*].write_capacity │ │ A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template expressions, etc are allowed here.

@MarkoE I want  a solution , how can I add GSI read, write capacity in ignore_changes

And have you tried with global_secondary_index.read_capacity and global_secondary_index.write_capacity?

yes ,I have tried and got error :  │   on ../tf-module/dynamodb/main.tf line 107, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "default": │  107:       global_secondary_index.read_capacity │ │ Block type "global_secondary_index" is represented by a set of objects, and set elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific criteria, use a "for" expression with an "if" clause.

ignore_changes blocks do not support variable resolution, and so you would need to specify each value individually. This also means the type in the for_each meta-parameter cannot be a set as the error message confirms. list is permitted for dynamic blocks.

You can only ignore specific static attribute paths with ignore_changes.
Therefore the closest possible solution is the following:
  ignore_changes = [
    global_secondary_index,
  ]

This will ignore changes to all attributes of all global_secondary_index blocks. There is no syntax to ignore only one attribute of all nested blocks of a given type, and no way to refer to a specific one because this provider has defined global_secondary_index as a set of objects and so there is no way to identify a single element to ignore.
